# Can't update cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I'm running into a strange problem, I can't update cookies. I'm perfectly able to read it and to set it (just the first time). Then every time I try to update it (for logout or update the cookie's info) nothing happens.

Basically when I login I use this code

```
$cookie_time = (3600 * 24 * 30); // 30 days
$cookietime = time() + $cookie_time;
$cookie_name = 'login';
$cookie_value = 'enter';    
setcookie ($cookie_name, 'id='.$selector.'&token='.$token, $cookietime);
```

and I can set it perfectly.

When I logout I use this code

```
$cookie_time = 1; // 1 days
$cookie_name = 'login';
$cookie_value = 'exit'; 
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $cookie_time);
```

The cookie doesn't change at all. Even if I try to login again without logging out (I made this possible by code) the cookie doesn't change. Looks like it's impossible to update it... I made many attempts but I have no ideas how to solve it! Is it possible that my PHP doesn't allow to set cookies that are already set?

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, $cookie_time should correspond to a timestamp relative to the 1 Jan 1970 and not only a time in ms.

see  http://php.net/manual/fr/function.setcookie.php

$cookie_time should be :

```
$cookie_time = time() + (3600 * 24 * 30);
```

the time() function returns the actual timestamp and $cookie_time now represents a expire date in the future ;)

Comment: yes, thanks I forgot to add this line of code that I already have in mine: 

`$cookietime = time() + $cookie_time;`   

any idea of how solving my problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the [setcookie docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

> Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your
>   script (this is a protocol restriction). This requires that you place
>   calls to this function prior to any output, including  and
>    tags as well as any whitespace.

Are you outputting anything before trying to update the cookie

Comment: I don't believe (I'm going to check again), but anyway as I wrote the same portion of code should work for update it (the login code) cause I can still access the login.php page when I logged in, and the cookie doesn't update